# How is this pointer constructor defined?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I do not understand how the below `Animal(Animal*)` constructor is defined. The code compiles and runs correctly.

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual ~Animal() {}
    virtual std::string specie() = 0;
    virtual std::string family() = 0;
};

class Rodent : public Animal {
public:
    std::string family() override { return "rodent"; }
};

class Rabbit : public Rodent {
public:
    std::string specie() override { return "rabbit"; }
};

int main() {
    Animal* goffy(new Rabbit());
}
```

`new Rabbit()` returns `Rabbit*` which by inheritance is `Animal*` so the constructor is taking a pointer to itself?

Comment: You may want to double check your posted code. Deer is never defined; as such, I get a compiler error in the main function.

Comment: Please show the definition of Deer::Deer()

Comment: Fixed the typo, thanks

Comment: There's no `Animal(Animal*)` constructor, nor one is needed. Pointers don't have constructors, they are built-in.

Comment: `Animal * goffy = new Rabbit();` might look easier for you to understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are performing [direct initialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

The expression `new Rabbit()` would return a `Rabbit*`. This `Rabbit*` value is then cast to a `Animal*` value, which is possible because `Animal` is a base class of `Rabbit`. The `Animal*` value is then assigned into the `goffy` variable.

Comment: Where is the copy initialisation? I see only direct initialisations in the code.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Since `goffy` is a pointer, it's exactly the same as

```
Animal* goffy = new Rabbit();
```

Comment: So it's just syntactic sugar?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "sugar", it's just syntactic regularity.

Comment: The form without `=` is generally preferred, as (prior to C++17 anyway) it does not specify unnecessary intermediate objects when used with class types

Comment: @M.M. Prior to c++17? I thought that enforced copy elision  where before everyone just assumed it wss done?

Comment: @rubenvb it specifies that in those scenarios there aren't even any "copies" to elide

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to object can be copied using the copy constructor just like usual objects on the stack.
However, there are a couple things happening here:

- First a `Deer` object is created on heap returning a pointer to its adress
- An `Animal` object is created using the copy constructor provided by
  the compiler by default, BUT instead of creating an exact copy, the
  `Deer` object is being sliced because `Animal` is it's base class.